# How to display child posts in the parent category

Tags: wp-query

I have a website. There the following structure:

> Parent Category:
>   Child category 1
>   Child category 2

In Parent Category I need display all posts of child category.

I write next WP query:

```
<?php
    $child_pages = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category__in' => 5,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'orderby' => 'title',
    )
);
?>
```

For the argument 'category__in' I set Parent category ID (its Parent category ID). But it is not working. In parent category posts not displayed.

How i get all child category posts on parent category?

Guys, and sorry for my English. Im in learning.. Yes, I'm ashamed))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `tax_query` with `WP_Query`. With a `tax_query`, by default, child terms are included to the term being set. Here is the example-

```
$args = array(
      'post_type'      => 'post', // Your post type
      'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num', 
      'meta_key'       => 'rankk', 
      'order'          => 'DESC', 
      'posts_per_page' => 100,
      'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'         => 'category', // Taxonomy name
                'field'            => 'term_id', // Means you'll use term id to determine your parent term.
                'include_children' => true,
                'operator'         => 'IN'
                'terms'            => 'YOUR PARENT CATEGORY ID', // Your term or category ID
            ),
        ),
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
        $q->the_post();
        the_title();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Hope this above helps.

Comment: Thank you sir for answer!

And in the field 'term_id' I should set child categories ID?

I mean argument 'field'    => 'term_id'.

Can I get all child categories posts?

Comment: @AlexGromov Please see my updated answer, I made it clear. And if this helps you then please accept the answer by **clicking the check sign or tick mark** at the **left of my answer**.

Comment: Please, sir, let me one question. We have field: 'terms'  => 'YOUR PARENT CATEGORY ID',

How correctly I should set Parent category ID? Just write ID number?

Comment: Yes. Write the ID number as a string or as far I can remember, you can pass an array too. Like either `'terms' => '23',` or `'terms' => 23`, or `'terms' => array( 23 ),`. As you like. But remember **here 23 is just a place holder**, use your term ID.

Comment: Thank you, sir! Thank you my American friend! Hello from Russia. Your code is working and help me.

Comment: Please, sir, let me one question. Your code is working. But in the field 'terms' I set static ID. Can I set dynamic ID? In more detail, the current category ID (for different pages).